# meanuver's direction attribute in Routing service's Response

Tags: here-api

I'm testing the routing service in API 3.0 and I can´t find the attribute "direction" in meanuver, this attribute exists in API 2.5, it attribute indicates the direction of the instruction for example "forward, straight, right.."

Does anybody know if there is some attribute that indicates the direction of the instruccion in the API 3.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the [migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions#js), there is a fundamental shift in the use of services between the **2.x** and **3.0** Here Maps APIs for JavaScript - previously the `Manager` objects decided a fixed format of for the request to the underlying REST APIs and encapsulated the response. Whereas now the full range of parameters can (and should) be set by the developer.

In the routing case the question is not so much "*What can the **3.0** API do?*" as "*How was the REST request fixed by the **2.x** API and how can I mimic the parts of that request that I need?*".

Looking at the Legacy API playground [simple routing example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/public/api-for-js/routing/map-with-route-from-a-to-b.html), the underlying REST request is:

[http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=shape&maneuverattributes=all&jsonAttributes=1&waypoint0=geo!52.516,13.388&waypoint1=geo!52.517,13.395&language=en-GB&mode=shortest;car;traffic:default;tollroad:-1&app_id=**APP_ID**&app_code=**TOKEN**...](http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=shape&maneuverattributes=all&jsonAttributes=1&waypoint0=geo!52.516222633265954,13.3889009369434&waypoint1=geo!52.51717584105763,13.395129026281722&language=en-GB&mode=shortest;car;traffic:default;tollroad:-1&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&xnlp=CL_JSMv2.5.4,SID_89087AD5-3243-4776-B20D-596DCD4F4934)

This can be reproduced precisely in the **3.x** API with the following:

```
 var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
    routeRequestParams = {
      routeattributes: 'shape',
      maneuverattributes: 'all',
      jsonAttributes :'1',
      waypoint0: '52.516,13.388',
      waypoint1: '52.517,13.395',
      language: 'en-GB',
      mode: 'shortest;car;traffic:default;tollroad:-1'
    };

  router.calculateRoute(...);
```

The next question here is what parameters do you really need for your application? The list for the [calculateRoute](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) endpoint of the *underlying* REST **Routing 7.2 API** includes the description of `maneuverattributes` showing how to obtain directions - with `maneuverattributes=...,direction`

So it may be possible to reduce the `routeRequestParams`  to something like:

```
var routeRequestParams = {
  routeattributes: 'shape',
  maneuverattributes: 'position,length,direction',  
  ...etc...
```

So in summary, you'll need to consult the REST Routing API documentation to define what you need first, before passing those parameters into the query of the Maps API for JavaScript `calculateRoute()` call.